# Installing Exchange in a RODC Site

Tags: active-directory, exchange, rodc

I'm trying to install Exchange 2010 to a server in a site that uses an RODC.  It tells me that "No domain controllers for the domain DOMAIN and the site SITE are available"

I'm going to be moving the Exchange server to the site with the main RW DC soon but I wanted to install Exchange before moving it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Exchange Server setup program requires a writeable Global Catalog Domain Controller (GC) in the Active Directory Site where the server is. A Read-Only Domain Controller (RODC) will not be used. You can't get around this requirement. Either temporarily promote a machine in the Site to be a DC or move the new Exchange Server machine to a different site.

Once the Exchange Server machine is operational you can remove the GC from the Site though this is strongly recommended against. Almost everything Exchange Server machines do (particularly the Client Access role) requires GC lookups.

Installing an Exchange Server does not require the Schema Master FSMO to be in the same site (or even accessible). Extending the schema (forestprep) does require the Schema Master to be operational and accessible, but this is an operation you do once per Active Directory forest before you do anything else with Exchange Server.

Answer (score 0):

If Im not mistaken you have to install Exchange in a site where a writeable DC exists and where the schema master exists, as Exchange needs to write changes to the schema, etc.

Comment: -1 I'm sorry Joe. I like you, but I downvote wrong information. Schema master doesn't need to be in the same site in order to install exchange. The schema needs to be extended if this is the first 2010 server to be installed, but that can be done from any 64-bit server that has the schema master in its site.

Comment: @Jason Berg: I understand. I should have been more explicit in my answer. I assumed the OP was extending the schema as part of the Exchange install and therefore would need to do it from a site with a writable GC and where the schema master exists. I should have been more specific.